# Laravel Date and Time need to split

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, view

Here is what i'm getting when i fetch data from its database.

[image]

So that i want to split into 2 different column.can anyone help me here?
Here is the view.

```
<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <th>Trainee ID</th>
        <th>Name with initials</th>
        <th>On time</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        @foreach($items as $item)
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                <td>{{ $item->time }}</td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You should cast `time` in your model as a date (in your model): `protected $casts = array('time'=>'date');` and then you would get a `Carbon` object which you can format

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<table class="table table-striped">
              <thead>
                <th>Trainee ID</th>
                <th>Name with initials</th>
                <th>On Date</th>
                <th>On Time</th>

              </thead>

              <tbody>
                @foreach($items as $item)
                <?php 
                  $temp = explode(' ',$item->time);
                ?>
                 <tr>

              <td>{{ $item->trainee_id }} </td>
              <td>{{ $item->name}}</td>
              <td>{{ $temp[0] }}</td>
              <td>{{ $temp[1] }}</td>

                </tr>

                @endforeach
              </tbody>

      </table>
```

try this

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
$timestamp = (strtotime($item->time));
$date = date('Y.j.n', $timestamp);
$time = date('H:i:s', $timestamp);

echo $date . "<br>" . $time;
```

you can display date and time in different columns now.

Comment: Thank u i find out the ans.

Answer (score 2):

Use `date()` and `strtotime()` like this

For date

```
{{ date("Y-m-d", strtotime($item->time)}}
```

For time

```
{{ date("H:i:s", strtotime($item->time)}}
```

You can use laravel carbon also

```
@php
    $input  = '2017-06-27 12:58:20';
    $format1 = 'Y-m-d';
    $format2 = 'H:i:s';
    $date = Carbon\Carbon::parse($input)->format($format1);
    $time = Carbon\Carbon::parse($input)->format($format2);
@endphp
```

Comment: Thank u i find out the ans.